# Installing RStudio on EMR

Tags: rstudio, emr, rstudio-server

I have a existing EMR cluster. How do I install RStudio on it. I see a lot of instruction on bootstrap action for installing RStudio on EMR. But according to my understanding they are used when creating a new cluster. How do I install Rstudio (or say Hbase if not already installed) on already existing EMR cluster?

Comment: What have you tried or where are you exactly stuck ? Did you search for solutions online already ? (Link them)

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install RStudio on master node. Add a new user and login to RStudio which will be running on https://masternode-ip:port

```
wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.446-x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install expect -y
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck -y rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.446-x86_64.rpm
sudo adduser analyst
sudo rstudio-server restart
```

follow steps from
http://spark.rstudio.com/ to run RStudio in cluster mode with SparkR

Answer (score 0):

I have written a blog article about this and I believe this will help you with you are after.

https://joarderkamal.wordpress.com/2016/12/14/first-blog-post/